# webgrid show the paging even if there is only one page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I am using the Webgrid in asp.net mvc3, and using it's build in paging and sorting.

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(rowsPerPage: 10, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "GridDiv");
    grid.Bind(source: Model);
    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);
}
```

The paging in the bottom shows something like this to switch between pages

```
1 2 3 4 5 >
```

When there is less then 10 rows in the model, there is only one page and the paging in the bottom disappear.

is there a way to make it show even if there is only one page?

```
1 >
```

Hope I was clear.
Thanks a lot

Comment: @Youssef....it's working for me when I have fewer rows than the page size. The only difference I can see in my code is canPage: true is an attribute in the WebGrid definition. Try new WebGrid(rowsPerPage: 10, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "GridDiv", canPage:true); Don't know if that will help but it's worth a shot

Comment: and what do you want the links to have ? "1 >" ??

Comment: @Yasser nothing. I just want that footer to show. because I am adding to it some more links. so when there is only one page the entire footer dissapear.

Comment: did this work ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030893/webgrid-show-the-paging-even-if-there-is-only-one-page/10040038#10040038

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick fix would be to check the TotalRowCount and manually add links,

```
@{
var grid = new WebGrid(rowsPerPage: 10, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "GridDiv");
grid.Bind(source: Model);
grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);

if(grid.TotalRowCount <= 10)
{
<a href="#">1</a>
<a href="#">></a>
}
}
```

this definitely is not a correct way to do so, also what are you planning to do on clicks on such links? are they just empty links then this is for you.